# Stream check not null on method using method reference

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, guava, method-reference

Given the following code

```
    List<Person> persons = ..;
    List<Person> personsWithoutAddress = 
            persons.stream().filter(p -> p.getAddress() == null)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

is there a way to inline use the method reference `Person::getAddress` in the filter ( maybe combined with `Objects::isNull` or with some Guava utility method...) without writing an extra utility method/Predicate ?

Comment: nope, there is not. but _why_?

Comment: A method reference is just clearer/easier to read, nothing more .. I was curious to understand if a simple null-check on a method return can be replaced with a syntax using method references

Comment: Really, you think something like `Function.of(Person::getAddress).andThen(Objects::isNull)` would be easier to read than `p -> p.getAddress() == null`, even if you could write it that way (which you cannot)? For one, it's a lot longer, and it is cumbersome to write, since you have to write out the class names, which could be a lot longer than the short `Address`.

Comment: `.filter(((Function<Person,?>)Person::getAddress).andThen(Objects::isNull)::apply)` and I hope, enlightenment is with you now.

Comment: Ok, if this is the minimal option I agree that it's a lot longer and less readable: `(Function<Person,?>)`, `andThen`, `apply` is too much overhead.